# Hive 0.12.0 IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: maven, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to install hive on my single node Hadoop installation.  I'm running Mint 16.  I've tried installing Hive 0.12.0 and 0.13.0.  I've added HIVE_HOME, HIVE_HOME/bin and HIVE_HOME/lib (and without lib) to my path.  Each time I run hive from the terminal I'm getting the following stack

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.createShim(ShimLoader.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

I've also attemped to compile hive from source but maven fails on the test's.  Has anyone else found a solution to this?

Edit:
I'm not running this in a VM.  I built the install on my system so I've seen a few things on google that suggest removing old thrift lib's on CDH and the like.

Running Oracle Java 1.8

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.4.0
Subversion http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1583262
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-03-31T08:29Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 375b2832a6641759c6eaf6e3e998147
This command was run using /opt/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.4.0.jar
```

When I try to compile hive:

```
testConfProperties(org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.TestHiveConf)  Time elapsed: 0.331 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1> but was:<null>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:647)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:128)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.TestHiveConf.checkHadoopConf(TestHiveConf.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.TestHiveConf.testConfProperties(TestHiveConf.java:64)
```

Comment: It would appear I was using the wrong maven version and I added -Dmaven.test.skip=true to my command so far so good.  Will report back if successful

Comment: I got it to build, still running into java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had a couple of issues.  I have to build with maven 3.0.5.  Then I had to skip tests during the build.  Finally, I had dueling jars and had to remove

```
/opt/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u1.jar
/opt/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u1.jar
```